# Can not reach mysql container running in different node with its service name, but can do with its container name

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 2 nodes in docker swarm mode, and deployed a mysql service on one node and a mysql client on the other node with 'docker stack deploy -c composeYaml stackName'. But it turns out the mysql client can not reach mysql by its service name 'mysql', but can do with its container name 'aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53'

Inside the client container, I can ping and nslookup 'mysql' container, but can not reach it with 3306 port

```
    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# ping mysql
    PING mysql (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
    64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
    64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
    64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
    ^C
    --- mysql ping statistics ---
    4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.042/0.052/0.007 ms

    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# nslookup mysql
    Server:   127.0.0.11
    Address:  127.0.0.11#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name: mysql
    Address: 10.0.2.2

    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# nmap -p 3306 mysql

    Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-19 09:34 UTC
    Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.49 seconds

    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# nmap -p 3306 10.0.2.2

    Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-19 09:41 UTC
    Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.48 seconds
```

But if I try with container name of 'mysql' got by 'docker ps', it's working, and its VirtualIP also working

On node where mysql container running:

```
    docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                 NAMES
    ebe25854c5b0        nysql:latest            "docker-entrypoint..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        3306/tcp                                              aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53
```

Back to inside the client container:

```
    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# nmap -p 3306 aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53

    Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-19 09:43 UTC
    Nmap scan report for aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53 (10.0.2.3)
    Host is up (0.000077s latency).
    rDNS record for 10.0.2.3: aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53.aqi_backend
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3306/tcp open  mysql
    MAC Address: 02:42:0A:00:02:03 (Unknown)

    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host

    root@ced2d59027e8:/opt/docker# nmap -p 3306 10.0.2.3

    Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-19 09:37 UTC
    Nmap scan report for aqi_mysql.1.yv9t12wm3z4s9klw1gl3bnz53.aqi_backend (10.0.2.3)
    Host is up (0.000098s latency).
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3306/tcp open  mysql
    MAC Address: 02:42:0A:00:02:03 (Unknown)

    Nmap done: 1
```

my compose file looks like follows:

```
    version: '3.2'
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql
        ports:
          - target: 3306
            published: 3306
            protocol: tcp
            mode: ingress
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
          MYSQL_DATABASE: aqitradetest
          MYSQL_USER: aqidbmaster
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: aqidbmaster
        deploy:
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
          placement:
            constraints: [node.hostname == prod-03]
        networks:
          - backend
      mysql_client:
        image: mysql_client
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
        deploy:
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 10s
            max_attempts: 3
            window: 30s
          placement:
            constraints: [node.hostname == production-01]
        networks:
          - backend
        depends_on:
          - mysql

    networks:
      frontend:
      backend:
```

Comment: Maybe share your compose yml. That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: compose file posted~ i tried both ingress and host mode (which is the default) for the 'ports' config of mysql service, but both bring the same problem

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but nevertheless you should know that depends_on is ignored in swarm.

Comment: `links` and network alias is the other options, but no idea if they are supported in swarm.

Comment: @herm thx for ur comment, and i've read the doc and known that there is no way to make services start in order~ well, this 'depends_on' is copied from a working example, i just left it there, plz see: https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app/blob/master/docker-stack.yml

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing some concepts.

In swarm when you publish a port it will be published on all nodes and accessible from outside using the IP of any of your nodes and that port (or using 0.0.0.0:port from an application on any of your nodes). Playing around with these ports won't help you access the other service by servicename.

When two services are on the same network (if you define no networks all services in the same compose file join the same default network) they should be able to reach all internal ports of the other service by servicename:port.

Probably there is a problem with your compose file. I would try to make a minimal compose file where you don't publish any ports on mysql and you don't define any networks because its easier to find an issue in a minimal compose file.

---

Most probably

```
ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
```

causes the problem.

Comment: It seems you are right... though nmap failed to detect the 3306 port against mysql service, I managed to login mysql database from inside mysql-client container. 2 more questions i want ask: 1. does 'expose: -3306' work if all ports are accessible across all nodes? 2. what does the 'frontend' and 'backend' mean in network definition? are they reserved key words? or I can use any name

Comment: Frontend and backend are not reserved keywords you can use any name.

Comment: To your first question. The [dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) states:
 "The Docker network feature supports creating networks without the need to expose ports within the network" so this exposing is optional and useless when using networks.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer!

Comment: If some comments or answers helped you it would be good to vote them up or accept the answer so that others who look for an answer know where to look. Also I would get some reputation :)